# Horizontally scrollable Listview

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-listview, android

My application uses a `ListView` to browse some text (source code).

I don't like that when the line is longer than the available space it automatically starts a new line like in the [image](http://www.xtremeshack.com/photos/20130922137980651757109.jpg), at line 312. Is there any way to set the layout so that horizontal scrolling is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

A few links to help you out:

1. [TableFixHeaders](https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders) - Android library that implements a table with fixed headers
2. [Android Horizontal ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) - a drop-in replacement for a standard ListView

Comment: The 1st one is good, but it lacks of the "setSelection" feature, that I need to implement the "go to line" feature.